# how get input value in a controller?

Tags: angularjs, http, search

i try to build an live search for an app. I made a ng change that logs the input (ng model searchLive) and reload the http request. But the $scope.searchlive returns undefined, the ng change works. suggestions?

my controller:

```
.controller('searchCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.change = function() {
    console.log($scope.searchLive);
    $scope.loadData();
}



$scope.loadData = function () {
        $http.get("http://example.com/?json=get_search_results&include=id,title&search="+ $scope.searchLive +"", {cache:false})
        .success(function(data) {$scope.zoekresultaat = data.posts; });
    };
```

})

my template

```
      <div class="list">
    <div class="item item-input-inset">
        <label class="item-input-wrapper">
            <input type="text" placeholder="zoek" ng-model="searchLive" ng-change="change()">
        </label>
    </div>            
    <a class="item " href="#/app/post/{{item.id}}" ng-repeat="item in zoekresultaat ">
      <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
      <p ng-bind-html="item.excerpt"></p>
      <p ng-show="item.excerpt == 0">Geen beschrijving</p>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: does the `html` which you have shown is in `ng-if`/`ng-switch`?

Comment: then your code looks great..could you reproduce the issue in plunkr?

Comment: What could be te problem if I use ng switch?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is nested scopes. http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html.

template:

```
 <div class="list">
        <div class="item item-input-inset">
            <label class="item-input-wrapper"
                <input type="text" placeholder="zoek" ng-change="change()" ng-model="search.term" >
            </label>
        </div>            
        <a class="item " href="#/app/post/{{item.id}}" ng-repeat="item in zoekresultaat ">
          <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
          <p>{{categories[0].title[}}</p>
        </a>
      </div>
```

controller:

```
.controller('searchCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

var pendingTask;

if ($scope.search === undefined) {
  $scope.search = { term:  ""};
  fetch();
}

$scope.change = function() {
  if (pendingTask) {
    clearTimeout(pendingTask);
  }
  pendingTask = setTimeout(fetch, 1000);
};

function fetch() {
  $http.get("http://www.example.com/?json=get_search_results&search=" + $scope.search.term + "&include=id,title,categories")
    .success(function(response) {$scope.zoekresultaat = response.posts; });

}
```

})

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use the controller scope ? for exemple,

```
 <div ng-controller="searchCtrl as ctrl">...</div>
```

in your js file you use this instead of $scope 
don't forget to inject $http in the dependency like

```
.controller('searchCtrl',['$http',function($http){

    this.searchLive = "";     

    this.change = function() {
        console.log(this.searchLive);
        this.loadData();
    }

    this.loadData = function () {
        var datas = []; 
        $http.get("http://example.com/?json=get_search_results&include=id,title&search="+ $scope.searchLive +"", {cache:false})
        .success(function(data) {datas = data.posts; });
        this.zoekresultaat = datas;
    };
}]);
```

I use a local variable to not have any conflict of scope

and your html become

```
<div class="list">
<div class="item item-input-inset">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper">
        <input type="text" placeholder="zoek" ng-model="ctrl.searchLive" ng-change="ctrl.change()">
    </label>
</div>            
<a class="item " href="#/app/post/{{item.id}}" ng-repeat="item in ctrl.zoekresultaat ">
  <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
  <p ng-bind-html="item.excerpt"></p>
  <p ng-show="item.excerpt == 0">Geen beschrijving</p>
</a>
```

I hope it will help you